# How to find words in a matrix - Python

Tags: python, matrix

I've made a function to search horizontally for a word in a matrix full of letters. Now I'm trying to reuse this code in order to find any word in matrix. I need to read the matrix line by line, compare the words made with my list of words (like a dictionary) and if the word exists in the list, a word has been found. 
This is my initial code:

```
def search(p):  
    x=matrix() #matrix of letters
    for line in x:
        if p in ''.join(line):
            return True
```

I've written some other code but none of it works. I've been looking for similar questions but none of them answer my question.

This is the code I have and doesn't work:

```
def auto_search():
    l=[] #list of words found
    x=matrix()
    for line in x:
        for i in ''.join(line):
            if search_dic(i)!=-1: #searchs in the list of words if the word is there
                l.append(i)
    print (l)
```

For example, a have this matrix:

```
[[a,p,e,n],
 [g,h,j,k],
 [e,r,l,d]]
```

The function has to read the matrix and find the word "pen" by itself.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hello Nancy, welcome to StackOverflow.  I see your problem, but could you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

```
def in_matrix(matrix, target):

    for my_list in matrix:
        my_str = ''.join(my_list)

        if target in my_str:
            return True
```

...

```
def search_matrix(matrix, targets):
    found = []

    for row in matrix:
        my_str = ''.join(row)

        for target in targets:
            try:
                my_str.index(target)  #Throws ValueError if target not in my_str
                found.append(target)  #This line skipped if ValueError
            except ValueError:
                pass

    return found



targets = ['pen', 'dog', 'horse']

matrix = [
    ['p','x','e','n'],
    ['g','d','o','g'],
    ['p','e','n','d']
]

print search_matrix(matrix, targets)

--output:--
['dog', 'pen']
```

...

```
import itertools as it

def word_in_permutations(target_word, permutations):
    for permutation in permutations:
        my_str = ''.join(permutation)

        try:
            my_str.index(target_word)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return False



def search_matrix(matrix, target_words):
    all_found = []

    for row in matrix:
        row_found = []

        for target_word in target_words:
            my_iter = it.permutations(row)

            if(word_in_permutations(target_word, my_iter)):
                row_found.append(target_word)

        all_found.append(row_found)

    return all_found



targets = ['pen', 'dog', 'pig']

matrix = [
    ['n','e','d','g','o','p'],
    ['g','o','d','g','i','p'],
]

print search_matrix(matrix, targets)

--output:--
[['pen', 'dog'], ['dog', 'pig']]
```

There are certain things you can do with all sequence types. These operations include indexing, slicing, adding, multiplying, and checking for membership. In addition, Python has built-in functions for finding the length of a sequence and for finding its largest and smallest elements.

Python Lists:
The list is a most versatile datatype available in Python which can be written as a list of comma-separated values (items) between square brackets. Good thing about a list is that items in a list need not all have the same type.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. The problem is that I'm trying to find the word in the matrix whithout a target. It's like an automatic search, but I don't really know how to do it. The function has to find the words by itself.

Comment: @Nancy, you have to have one or more targets.  A computer program does not know innately what a word is.

Comment: If I try to make all the possible combinations of word in my matrix and compare them with a list full of words (like a dictionary), would it work?

Comment: The itertools module has a function that will return all permutations of a list of letters.  Then you can search the permutations for your target words.  See the additional example I posted.

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd suggest that you look for ways to transpose the matrix into other matrices such that you can re-use your scanning code on each of them.  For example you want to take your matrix:

```
a p e n
g h j k
e r l d
```

(rendered here without punctuation for brevity) ... and transpose it thus:

```
a g e
p h r
e j l
n k d
```

... column-wise.  You can then scan that with your code.  This is effectively the same as writing a new function to scan each column "downwards" for your target word(s).

You can also reverse each line of the original matrix and of this transposed matrix to scan "backwards" and "upwards" respectively.

I would re-write your *search()* function to take two arguments --- a matrix and a target.  Then you can call it with the initial matrix, and the transposed matrix.  I'd also modify the *search()* function to search each row forwards and backwards (and I might make that last part optional).

So my *search()* function would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def search(matrix, target, rev=True):
    for each in matrix:
        if target in ''.join(each):
            return True
        if rev and target in ''.join(reversed(each)):
            return True
    return False
```

And I need a *transpose()* function which, as it happens, can be trivially simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def transpose(matrix):
    return zip(*matrix)
```

Now my main code path would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
if search(matrix, target) or search(transpose(matrix), target):
    print "%s found in matrix" % target
```