# Finding word in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, cpu-word

I have a matrix file (which python reads like a list of lists) and I need to tell if a word from a different file appears in that matrix, in a given direction.
for example: given this matrix:

```
c,a,T,e
o,a,t,s
w,o,t,e
n,o,l,e
```

the words:

```
caT, cow, own, cat
```

and the directions:

```
downright (diagonal)
```

I expect an output:

```
cat:1
```

and for the direction:

```
down, right
```

I expect:

```
cow:1
own:1
cat:1
```

my function is set like so:

```
def word_finder(word_list,matrix, directions):
```

**What I find hard to do is go through a list of lists and run over indexes that are horizontal for example or diagonal :(**
thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

There already seem to be several partial answers to your question. While it would not be efficient, with some simple parsing of the directions you could easily chain together the following separate solutions to come up with an answer to your problem.

- Diagonal Traversal: [In Python word search, searching diagonally, printing result of where word starts and ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241719/in-python-word-search-searching-diagonally-printing-result-of-where-word-start)
- Linear Traversal: [How to find words in a matrix - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696199/how-to-find-words-in-a-matrix-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

matrix= [['c', 'a', 'T', 'e'],
         ['o', 'a', 't', 's'],
         ['w', 'o', 't', 'e'],
         ['n', 'o', 'l', 'e']]
words = ['caT', 'cow', 'own', 'cat']

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in chain(matrix, list(zip(*matrix))): # list(zip(*matrix)) is for down direction
    for word in words:
        if word in ''.join(i):
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
```

The `d` will be your expected output. `{'caT': 1, 'cow': 1, 'own': 1}`